# TinyMCE how to append baseURL to LINK and base Path for images

Tags: javascript, editor, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMCE for Editing my site content.

In Local I've different path for my base url and on development server its different and on production its different.

Is there any way to define the something like `baseURL` for my links and `basePath` for Images to be linked.

I want to define `baseURL` to all my links and `basePath` to my all the Images.

Right now I'm working on my local and I've created few pages. But when I've thought of dev and production It will be difficult to do the path changing task. Please desperately need some solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to set these three options:

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
document_base_url : "http://www.example.com/path1/"
```

According to the [TinyMCE documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/), this will convert all relative urls to fully qualified URLs, based on the base you provide.

[image: Screenshot of the relevant TinyMCE documentation]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
        function myCustomURLConverter(url, node, on_save, name) {
            // Do some custom URL conversion
            if (name == "src")
            {
                url = window.location.origin +"/uploads/" + url
            }
            // Return new URL
            return url;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I undestand the question, but wouldn't this provide what you're looking for?

```
var base = "http://"+window.location.host;
// base = "http://stackoverflow.com"
var img_base = base + "/img"
// img_base = "http://stackoverflow.com/img"
```

Comment: No this is not I want I want some configuration in the TinyMCE editor which will automatically take care when i same `<img src="flower.jpg" />` automatically add entire path or whatever base path we've added. Its alright if its `<img src="Some_const/flower.jpg" />` Hope this is clear for you.